# dropdown menu not able to select - angular 4

Tags: angular, select, bootstrap-4, dropdown

I have a dropdown like this.

[image]

```
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle form-group"  data-toggle="dropdown"
            aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            <span id="selected">view</span>
            </button>
            <div class="dropdown-menu arrow form-group">
                <a class="dropdown-item" *ngFor="let result of results?.results">{{result?.name}}</a>
              <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
              <a class="dropdown-item" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#default">Add</a>
            </div>
```

I have this code in js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.dropdown-menu a').click(function () {
    $('#selected').text($(this).text());
  });
});
```

When I click on "Add", 
"View" text is being replaced by Add but this is not happening when I click result 1 and result 2. It is not being selected when clicked on result 1 and result 2

Also, I want to show the result 1 as default instead of view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the problem is that those two buttons (`result 1/2`) are created after you call the jquery binding. You can do this to bind also to elements added in future:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(document).on('click', '.dropdown-menu a', function () {
    $('#selected').text($(this).text());
  });
});
```

Btw this is something that you should use angular for anyway... :]

Comment: Perfect. How do I get the first result as default in place of view domains?

Comment: do it in angular controller of that component, introduce new (public) variable, set it to the first item after loading the `results`, and use that inside the template like `<span id="selected">{{ activeItem }}</span>`.

Comment: i tried this in controller   this.activeItem = this.results; and activeItem: any but activeItem is undefined

Comment: This is a bit outside of scope of this question. Try opening new one and provide what you tried. My bet is you are assigning it sooner than the `results` var itself. Also you should put there just the first item of `result` array.